# Ajax Success Wont Trigger

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

On submitting a form I wanted to provide the user with feedback that the ajax was executed successfully. My ajax is as follows:

```
  $(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function (e) {
                var url = "{{ url_for('handle_data') }}"; // send the form data here.
                var form_data = new FormData($('#mainform')[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: form_data, // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success!!');
                    }
                });
                 e.preventDefault(); // block the traditional submission of the form.
            });

             // Inject our CSRF token into our AJAX request.
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ form.csrf_token._value() }}")
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

And on the backend my flask is:

```
@app.route('/handle_date', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_data():
    """
    :return:
    """
    print("hi there")
    return ""
```

I can never get that success alert message to fire.

Comment: Check out the network tab. See the status of the request.

Comment: the status is 200

Comment: What type of content your server is receiving? json / text?
$.ajax({
                url: 'users.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    $('#response pre').html( data );
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is not receiving JSON, it’s a FormData. And for jQuery to send a FormData, it needs

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: formData,

    // these three additional parameters
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json"
})
```

The second edit i did was at the backend, when returning a response from flask I had to wrap it under jsonify for the ajax success to trigger